# How to Delete the inserted row from the DB in soapUI

Tags: database, testing, soap, soapui

(NOTE:I'm beginner in soapUI)

I've service called (Register customer) so when I finish the testing i'd like to 
delete the inserted row from the database , how can I do it ? . Thanks

Comment: Probably create another service that will do the "Delete Customer" and keep it exposed for Development alone, until you want it to be available in production as well.

Comment: can't i just use JDBC test step and write the SQL there? and thank you so much

Comment: Yes, that's another way.

Comment: @ReamSuliman, have you tried with jdbc test step? what happened?

Comment: Yes I have , it's worked fine.
  Thanks to Ravi